Flutter - detect whether the browser available or not in iOS
I know how to check browser availability in Android using the method channel. Is there any way we can detect whether the browser is available in an iPhone?

Your'e probably looking for url_launcher's canLaunchUrl

I tried but it is getting true in iOS though the browser is unavailable

Have you read the docs?
On recent versions of Android and iOS, this will always return false unless the application has been configuration to allow querying the system for launch support. See the README for details.

https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#configuration

Firstly I disabled the browser in iOS this way:

On your iOS device, open Settings.
Select Screentime > Content & Privacy Restrictions > Allowed Apps.
Enter your Screen Time Passcode. Depending on your iOS version, you may be required to enter your passcode in the previous step.
Toggle Safari to ON or OFF.


I am trying to check it in iPhone15  if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(My_URL_GOES_HERE))) { it is returning true

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You might want to look at url_launcher's canLaunchUrl:

Checks whether the specified URL can be handled by some app installed on the device.

Future<bool> isBrowserAvailable() async {
  const String testUrl = 'http://www.blablabal.com';
  if (await canLaunch(testUrl)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}


To address your comment stating that you have turned of the browser, but it's still returning True:
If we look at url_launcher's implementation of canLaunchUrl for iOS, we can see it directly calls the native iOS method of canOpenURL:
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/557d3284ac9dda32a1106bb75be8a23bdccd2f96/packages/url_launcher/url_launcher_ios/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.m#L88

- (BOOL)canLaunchURL:(NSString *)urlString {
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
  UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
  return [application canOpenURL:url];
}

So, there must be something on your device allowing it to open URLs. Perhaps another browser app is installed?

For me await canLaunch(testUrl) is always giving true even though it is disabled in settings.

I want to handle the edge case like, if no browser available to open then I want to show a popup to the user "Hey no browser available right now, please install/enable it to continue".
